# Define measurement to test different data sets with the same algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, algorithms, measurement, boosting

So I'm having an xgboost model "xgbm" which for a set of features, gives me a prediction between [0, 1]

```
xgbm(f1, ... fn) = [0, 1]
```

the model works fine and I measure its success with `ROC AUC`.

now if i'd wanted to check between different xgbm models, lets say xgbm1 vs xgbm2 the result I would get from the `ROC AUC` would be sufficient.

My problem is that for the same algorithm, xgbm I'd like to check different data sets. (my objective is to find the best constaint_x that will generate trainx/testx) which I will verify with my model.

which means that with constaint1 I will get a train1/test1 set for the xgbm and with constaint2 I will get a train2/test2 set for the xgbm.

But, alas. I cannot compare between the two because the ROC AUC is not good to compare between 2 different enviorments/datasets, but between different algorithms on the same data set.

Could anyone recommend a measurement that will help me measure which training/testing set (or which constaint) will produce the best result?

a little about the problem:
Its a ranking problem that I address as a `'binary:logistic'`. the target is 0 for fail and 1 for success. the ratio on the events (dataset) between 1s and 0s is 0.08.

Please comment anything you need for me to clarify the problem for you.